# send new email windows live - from command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, mailto, windows-live

I've read [this guide](http://email.about.com/od/outlookexpresshacks/qt/Command_Line_Mail_in_Windows_Live_Mail_or_Outlook_Express.htm) in order to create a new email directly with Windows Live Mail from a batch file but I have problem with the double quotes.

This is my batch file:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Mail\wlmail" /mailurl:mailto:"mymail@gmail.com?subject=blabla&body=Hi there"
exit
```

This give me the following result in the WLM window:

> To: "mymail@gmail.com
>
> subject: blabla
>
> body: Hi There"

I have one problem:

- The double quotes appear before the recipient and at the end of the body.

I tried:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Mail\wlmail"
  /mailurl:mailto:mymail@gmail.com?subject=blabla&body=Hithere
```

> To: mymail@gmail.com
>
> subject: blabla
>
> body:               (empty)

or:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Mail\wlmail"
  /mailurl:mailto:"mymail@gmail.com?subject=blabla&body=Hi there
```

> To: "mymail@gmail.com
>
> subject: blabla
>
> body: Hi There

Any help would be appreciated!

PS: the "Mailto URL Encoder" of the guy make things worste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Windows Mail or any Microsoft mailer, but I guess that this should work for you.

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Mail\wlmail" 
     /mailurl:mailto:mymail@gmail.com?subject=blabla^&body=Hithere
```

As your sample looks quite correct, but the `&` before `body=` will split the command line into two parts, and now the caret `^` escapes it, so the body should be visible.